# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' after android studio V3.1.1 update

Tags: android, android-update-sdk

I just updated android studio to V3.1.1. Then my program went wrong.
When build the program,there are two errors:

[image]

1. One in 'Run build':

   org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'

[image]

2. Another in Java compiler:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.checkers.SimpleDeclarationChecker

[image]

Here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'




android {
    compileSdkVersion 26


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.restress.saniauto"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}


androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}


buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
        // quickly to Android tooling updates
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    //RxJava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.8'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxkotlin:0.55.0'
    //Room & RxAndroid2
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$room_version"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"
    //Design
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:26.1.0'
  
}
```

Comment: Did you tried a clean build? (aka rebuild)

Comment: yes,but clean&rebuild didnt work.

Comment: failed again,still the same errors

Comment: Open <root project>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and read Gradle version. It should be at least 4.4. If that doesn't work try 4.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well,I finally get over this.
When I use `--stacktrace`,I find the `:app:kaptDebugKotlin` is a procedure in BUILDING an android program.
[--stacktrace result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GumTr.jpg)

And I get the error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.checkers.SimpleDeclarationChecker` in this `:app:kaptDebugKotlin` procedure.

I doubt that there're something new in kotlin implementation,so I update my kotlin_version from 1.2.21 to 1.2.30.

Then I get more clear errors.That is the `room` parameters errors.
[room error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgqiY.png)

So I change the `arg0` to the `parameter name in Dao functions` in SQL query.

Finally it works.

Comment: @resress: I'm beginner android dev, can you explain how to using `--stacktrace`? because I have same error and still doesn't work for me.

Comment: ```./gradlew build --stacktrace```

Comment: Updating kotlin version helped.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the test project. Using dagger with Kotlin and this task failing was a blocker.

I tried many ways but the error message was not meaningful, the very next day I Start copying classes to a new project and found that issue is due to dagger and also convert Moshi annotation `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)` java class into Kotlin.

`MoviesViewModel @Inject constructor(private val movieService: MovieService): ViewModel()`

then :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and solved by updating the kotlin to the latest version (1.5.31) in my project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For people trying to use **Jetpack Compose** running into this error.

For me I was missing the `composeOptions{...}` block so I added it as shown below and the error is resolved now.

```
buildFeatures {
    compose = true
    viewBinding = true
}

composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.0.1"
    kotlinCompilerVersion = "1.5.21" // Make sure this version is same as your Kotlin version
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I downgrade the kotlin plugin version from 1.8.20 to 1.7.20 in build.gradle in root project like below:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
}
```